# How to use the "Reusing Workflows" feature in github?

Tags: maven, github-actions

If would like to use the new "reusable workflows" feature for my Maven builds:

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/reusing-workflows

Unfortunately, I did not figure out where I need to activate the beta feature. Or should it work out of the box, without any additional activation?

Comment: I've actually followed what is explained in the documentation you shared, on a personal repository, and it's already available without needing any activation or extra setup.

Comment: Great! Then I probably just made an error somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a new beta program like "projects", where workflows are also used (as in "[Automating projects (beta)](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/trying-out-the-new-projects-experience/automating-projects)") there is an explicit "[signup process](https://github.com/features/issues)".

But for "reusable workflows", that feature might already be available, considering there is already a [feedback/discussion](https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/6110) with:

- an [example repository](https://github.com/elben10/action-composition)
- an [example workflow](https://github.com/elben10/action-composition/actions/runs/1319321083/workflow) (invalid, but for another reason)